# GridView cells with different heights

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am creating an android app and I have a page that displays many cards at once. These cards have constant widths (so that two fit next to each other on the page) however they all have different heights. I want to display them in a grid formation where they fit together without any gaps like the notes app on the material design "Cards" page - http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-usage - 
(about 1/8th down the page). My question is, does anybody know how to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi again, I noticed your name and you were responsive. So I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we had [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), it's enough to [setLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager)) using [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html).

You can find more instructions  [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have looked into your link and I think this will work. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have not implemented Gridview but I believe you want to manipulate its layouts, like in ListView. For a start, a link is at [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). Look at setLayoutParams method. It will give you good ideas.

Comment: Thank You for your response, the only problem with a grid view is that it sets the height of the rows to its highest element (leaving gaps) and I am not sure how to overcome this.